# Function to check numbers are prime numbers

Tags: c#, loops, primes, do-while

I need to be able to check that two numbers entered by the user (`p` and `q`) are prime numbers, and if they aren't prime numbers then the user is asked to re-enter a prime number until a prime number has been entered for both `p` and `q`. If I enter a number which isn't a prime number, I am asked to enter another number, if I enter a prime number the second time round it tells me the prime number isn't a prime number. How can I correct this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Math;
using System.Numerics;

namespace primenumbers
{
class Program
{
int Check_Prime(BigInteger p)         
        {
            if (p <= 1) return 0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= p / 2; i++)
            {
                if (p % i == 0)
                {
                    return 0; //not a prime number
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }

        static void  result (BigInteger p)
        {
            int result = Check_Prime(p);
            if (Check_Prime(p) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" is a prime number");                    
            }

           else  do
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(" is not a prime number");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a prime number");
                    p = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                } while (result == 0);                
        }
        static int Check_Prime_Q(BigInteger q)

        {
            if (q <= 1) return 0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= q / 2; i++)
            {
                if (q % i == 0)
                {
                    return 0; //not a prime number
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }

        static void resultq(BigInteger q)
        {
            int result = Check_Prime_Q(q);

            if (Check_Prime_Q(q) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" is a prime number");
            }

            else do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" is not a prime number");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a prime number");
                    q = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                } while (result == 0);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger p; // = 61; //value of p

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a prime number for p");
            p = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          result(p);


            BigInteger q; //53; //value of q

            Console.WriteLine("Ener a prime number for q");
            q = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            resultq(q);
            result(p);

            BigInteger n = p * q; // calculation for n

            Console.WriteLine("p = " + p);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("q = " + q);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("n = " + n);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are doing too much work; you only need to check to `sqrt(p)`, at least; see [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that many things in the code could be improved (like naming, return values, `p` and `q` mistaken in `Main`) the main problem lays here. You are incrementing `i` to `p/2` and right after that you are checking `if (i == p)` which is never going to be true (except for `p = 0`)

```
static int Check_Prime(BigInteger p)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= p /2; i++)
    {
        if (p % i == 0)
        {
            return 0; //not a prime number
        }
    }
    if (i == p) // never true except p == 0
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; // always returns 0
}
```

Simply remove the `if` statement and return `1`.

```
static int Check_Prime(BigInteger p)
{
    if (p <= 1) return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= p /2; i++)
    {
        if (p % i == 0)
        {
            return 0; //not a prime number
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I've done that but it if  I purposefully put a number that isn't a prime number and then input a prime number it tells me the prime number isn't a prime number?